# 「つきおうて」や「あいおうて」はどういう意味でしょうか？

Tags: grammar, meaning, archaic-language, literature

こんにちは、

川上弘美著の「神様」の小説を読んでいます。
「河童玉」という章で、ある男河童が女河童についてこう言っています。

> 三百年も**つきおうてござります**から、些かのいさかいもありましたし気持ちが行き違うこともありました、つまりはまあ山も谷もあったということでございますが、三百年にしては波瀾は少なかったほうであるように思います。儂と女河童はなんといっても気持ちが寄り添ってござったし、それよりも何よりも、あちらの方が素晴らしく**あいおうていた**のです。

現在の日本語とは違った言葉がありますが、
以上の「つきおうて」や「あいおうて」はどういう意味でしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: つきおうて=付き｛つき｝合う｛おう｝て。と思います。https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E5%90%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%9F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> つきおうて＝つきおう＋て＝付き合う＋て
>
> あいおうていた＝あいおう＋て＋いる＋た＝[相会う](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9B%B8%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%86)＋て＋いる＋た

This is from [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8) about ワア行五段.

> ワア行五段活用で連用形が促音便化するものが、西日本方言や古風な文体ではウ音便化することがある。この場合「ワローテ（笑うて/わろうて）」「ユーテ（言うて/いうて）」「ソーテ（沿うて/そうて）」のように発音する。

You can still see this conjugation in forms like 問うて、問うた.

おう is an old way to pronounce of [あう](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%88%E3%81%86). I wonder if it's related to 逢瀬{おうせ}, but I have no idea about that one.

Comment: How would one pronounce おう in おうて？As a long お as in おおき or as distinct お and う sounds like at the end of 整う？

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's a long お, but it's old speech so I can't be certain. 問うて is pronounced with a long お though.